# Juntar resultados repetidos - PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Bom dia a todos, estou com uma dúvida para juntar resultados repetidos na consulta no Mysql feita pelo PHP.

É o seguinte o código que estou usando no momento ele removeu a primeira repetição de valores na consulta, mas tem outro campo que também deve ser removido as duplicações, já tentei várias combinações que eu entendo e nada deu certo, ele está retornando desse jeito:

```
Cliente Tipo Análise
   1      1    0001
          1    0002
---------------------
   2      1    0100
```

E estou querendo fazer assim:

```
Cliente Tipo Análise
   1      1    0001
               0002
---------------------
   2      1    0100
```

Reparem que no campo Tipo, está repetindo os valores.

Eu tenho N clientes, e esse cliente tem N análises, eu não posso repetir o cliente na pesquisa e nem o tipo, por que vai juntar tudo na parte de Análise, formando uma lista.

O código que estou usando no momento:

```
$query = mysqli_query( $db, 'SELECT * FROM laudos ORDER BY cliente, tipo');
$cli = array();

while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $cli[$row['cliente']][] = $row;
}
?>

<table border="1" cellpadding="10">
<tr>
    <td>Cliente</td>
    <td>Tipo</td>
    <td>Análises</td>
</tr>
<?php 
    foreach($cli as $cliente => $values){
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $cliente; ?></td>
    <?php foreach($values as $resul) { ?>
    <tr>            
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $resul['tipo'];?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option SELECTED>Escolha um laudo</option>
                <option><?php echo $resul['legisla'].'-'.$resul['numero'];}?></option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tr>
    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

boas tenta ser mais claro, não posso comentar.

queres usar combobox com os valores é?

porque de fazer assim   $cli[$row['cliente']][] = $row;?

a forma correta é  $rows['nome table'] = $row; ou  $rows[] = $row; para tirar todos os campos bd

Comment: depois tens de ir a coluna tipo e ver se o indice anterior já existe algo como if(tipo[i]==tipo[i++]){echo }else{}